# Non Resizing full width image with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

To have a full width image - Either we use an `img` tag with `width:100%` or we use a `div` with `background-image`. In both the cases the image resize with viewport.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/yp3j6qwx/):**

Above Fiddle uses `background-image` property. I have tried all the background options but all of them resizes the image at some point.

**Is there a way that I can keep a full width image which does not resize with browser resize?** It can have hide some portion from left or right but not resize.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  background: url(https://i1.wp.com/hyderabad-india-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/hyd-urban-main.png) center/cover;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 53%;
  top: 52%;
}
```

**MY CASE**
The reason I want this behavior is, I need to position something on a map image. I am not allowed to use google map API. And the marker must be at the exact position for all viewport size.

Alternate solution:
If the solution is not possible, I am thinking of adding the marker into the image and use the [`area`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) tag.

But I am not sure if that solution is all browser compatible.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/yp3j6qwx/):**

Comment: I don't understand...  So you want it to fill an area when the page loads but then  not change size if the window resizes?  Sounds like you could have the image fill a div but just set the size of the div in javascript when the page loads?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat. Yes that might be a solution I guess.

Comment: Is the marker supposed to be in the center of the map or can it be anywhere?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat It must be at a specific position on the image. Say the image is 3000x240 then the marker should be always at 1000x100. Much like a marker on google map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the height and width as absolute pixel values using Javascript. See your updated fiddle and snippet below: https://jsfiddle.net/LaurensSwart/yp3j6qwx/4/

This way, when the page loads, the div is set to 100% of the viewport, but the width and height are then absolute values (and not percentual, they don't change when the viewport is resized).
Hope it helps!

```js
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

$('#map').css('width',w).css('height',h);
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  background: url(https://i1.wp.com/hyderabad-india-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/hyd-urban-main.png) top left/cover; /* The position of the map needs to be fixed, i.e. top-left */
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 380px; /* These should be absolute values */
  top: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
<a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note: you would still have to set absolute pixel values for the position of the `a` (map marker), because with percentual values, it would be different for every different viewport (when the page loads). You should also position the background top-left, as opposed to center-center, otherwise your "coordinates" would also shift if someone with a smaller or bigger viewport loads the page.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Add `scroll` to your `background` style property

```
background: url("demo.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
background-size: initial
```

Your jsfiddle updated on the following link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yp3j6qwx/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this just change `background-size: contain` and added `no-repeat`, `center`.

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i1.wp.com/hyderabad-india-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/hyd-urban-main.png) no-repeat center center;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: contain;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 53%;
  top: 52%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That will resize the image after specific viewport